# Pseudo elements are not working in Material-UI makeStyles React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui, root

Pseudo elements are not working in Material-UI  makeStyles .

```
innerBox: {
        borderRadius: "10px",
        background: "#fff",
        boxShadow: "0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36)",
        maxHeight: "50px",
        "& ::before": {
            content: "anything"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here seems to be your selector, it's not correct instead of `& ::before` try `&:before`

```js
innerBox: {
    borderRadius: "10px",
    background: "#fff",
    boxShadow: "0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36)",
    maxHeight: "50px",
    "&:before": {
        content: "anything"
    }
}
```

Comment: Then something else is wrong in your code, but the selector works, check this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-sound-i9tb1 It uses both `:before` and `:after`

Comment: innerBox: {
    borderRadius: "10px",
    background: "#fff",
    boxShadow: "0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36)",
    maxHeight: "50px",
    "&:before": {
        content: " ' ' "
    }
}                                                                                                                                                  its work bro